# I am using ubuntu14.04. I have installed numpy in python3, but it is not in python2.7.

Tags: numpy

I have installed both python3-numpy as well as python-numpy from the App store. But then, numpy only works on python3. I want it to work on python2.7 also.

Comment: How did you install it? Using `pip` or `apt-get` or the Software Center?

Comment: I install it in the software center. Sorry for the typo, it is not the App store.

Comment: Try it from the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T will open one): `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`.

Comment: I remember I have tried this before. But it does not work.

Comment: Define "it does not work", please. [Edit] your question and show the output of `sudo apt-get install python-numpy && python2 -V && python2 -c "import numpy; print numpy.__version__"`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. This problem was caused by my earlier installation of another software, which is called PSI4. PSI4 is a quantum chemistry software, which was built in a way that it also includes python2.7.10. Therefore, after the installation, when I typed the command "python", something as below will show up:

```
cpjwong@cpjwong-OptiPlex-9020:~$ python
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:50:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>>
```

You can see the company name "Continuum Analytics, Inc.", which implies that the pre-installed python2.7 in ubuntu 14.04 has been overwritten. The numpy for this version of python can be installed by firstly downloading numpy-1.7.0.tar.gz and then run the following command:

```
tar xvzf numpy-1.7.0.tar.gz
cd numpy-1.7.0/
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
cd ..
```

Then, you can check whether numpy is properly installed by typing the following command:

```
cpjwong@cpjwong-OptiPlex-9020:~$ python
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:50:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import numpy
>>>
```